# UWP HandwritingView can be enabled only for English

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, handwriting

As mentioned in this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/controls/text-handwriting-view), the UI control - HandwritingView, can be built into textbox.

To test this feature, I wrote a UWP app as below:

```
<Page 
    Loaded="onPageLoaded"
    x:Class="hwv.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:hwv"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Width="1440"
    Height="1300"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbHandWriteView" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" FontSize="60" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1300" Height="1200" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

private void onPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tbHandWriteView.IsHandwritingViewEnabled = true;
    tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse;
    tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.PlacementAlignment = HandwritingPanelPlacementAlignment.TopLeft;
    tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.Width = 1300;
    tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.Height = 500;
    tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    bool bOpenHandWriteInTb = tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.TryOpen();
}
```

It goes well when English (United States) is adopted as current keyboard input language.
In the end of the above code, TryOpen() method will return true, and I can do handwrite and recognition in the textbox, as expected.

However, when I switch to other keyboard input language, such as Japanese and Chinese, TryOpen() method will return false without any information. The HandwritingView UI will be unavailable, and then just turn into a normal textbox.

In System Settings, the handwriting packages had been already installed for Japanese and Chinese, as screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdYPX.jpg).

I have also tried Language property of UI controls:
`tbHandWriteView.Language = "ja-JP";`
`tbHandWriteView.HandwritingView.Language = "ja-JP";`
, but my problem is still there.

Thanks in advance if any idea.

Comment: Add these `TryOpen()` codes in the [Page Loaded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.loaded?view=winrt-22621) event, will the same problem be reproduced?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT Hi, as you said, I've moved TryOpen() into onPageLoaded(), and the problem still exists.

Comment: I tested this on win10 surface and it works for me when using Japanese and Chinese, what is your test device?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I tested it on win11 22H2 device. Is there any possible mistake in my code snippet?

Comment: Try creating a new blank UWP project and don't add any more code in MainPage(), only add that tbHandWriteView code in the PageLoaded event.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT As your suggestion, I had created a new blank UWP and modified my code, and also edited the code section in my post correspondingly . Unfortunately, same situation was still observed. I was wondering if any difference between us...

Comment: This is my test picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ptft.png , I tested Japanese and Chinese, HandwritingView opened successfully. If possible, could you test it on other devices?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT I had tested on three devices (all Win11 Pro 22H2 OS build:22621), all of them failed as the same problem.
I am curious about that, after you got 'true' from TryOpen(), did you actually handwrite Japanese/Chinese on UI and recognized successfully?

Comment: Yes, I tested in Chinese and Japanese, my device (Win11 Pro 22H2 OS build:22621.1413). Win11 has [new OS Build 22621.1778](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-24-2023-kb5026446-os-build-22621-1778-preview-3c547100-7a73-4ae6-bb7d-ebd02e87dc04), you can try to update to the latest version.